# Change wordpress to display search results in chronological order

Tags: wordpress, search

This is a Thesis theme site using the core WP search functionality. Not looking for a new plugin solution, just how to alter the search results to change order of posts from relevance to chronological order. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some of native wp search results, like terms do not have any type time info stored. You can  use WP_User_Query with order of records. It will be not exactly what you expected but will have chronological order:

```
$args = array(
'search'    => 'search_patern_from_form',
'orderby'   => 'id',
'order'     => 'DESC'
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

See order by section of  [WP_User_Query codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)